# Non-Zero Expectation, Dependent, Uncorrelated Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Do there exist non-zero expectation, dependent, uncorrelated random variables $X$ and $Y$? The examples that I have found have at least one of the variables have zero expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ have standard normal distribution. Then $1+X$ and $1+X^{2}$ satisfy your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Take any example and add nonzero constants to $X$ and $Y$.  This changes the expectations but does not affect dependency or correlation.